# Swift: didExitRegion delay causes missed beacon events

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am monitoring for two beacons defined as beaconRegion1 (Room 1) and beaconRegion2 (Room 2), and I am logging enter and exit events for each (because we want to calculate time-spent-in-room).

I am experiencing a challenge in logging the exits because of the slight delay that occurs when `didExitRegion` fires.

***Real World:***

Time 0:00 (minutes:seconds): Person enters Room 1.

Time 10:00:  Person exits Room 1.

Time 10:15:  Person enters Room 2.

Time 20:00: Person exits Room 2.

***Swift/iOS World:***

Time 0:00: Person enters Room 1, didEnterRegion fires for beaconRegion1 (Room 1)

**Time 10:00: Person exits Room 1. Crickets chirp.**

Time 10:15: Person enters Room 2, didEnterRegion fires for beaconRegion2 (Room 2)

**Time 10:30: didExitRegion belatedly fires for beaconRegion1 (Room 1)**

Time 20:00 Person exits Room 2, but no exit is detected because Exit 1 was delayed by ~30 seconds and therefore programmatically occurred after the Room 2 entry was triggered.

In short, the delay allows the second entry to precede the first exit and so the second exit never triggers.

I understand the `didExitRegion` delay is unavoidable.  I'm curious if there are workarounds to catch the second exit in this example, perhaps by delaying when didEnterRegion fires to allow the first exit to "catch up" or perhaps by running separate didEnter and didExit functions for each beaconRegion?  Swift seems intent on forcing me to use `CLRegion` or `CLBeaconRegion` as the region: parameter for `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`.

Code Example:

```
let beaconRegion1 = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "...")!, major: 12345, minor: 12345, identifier: "Room1")

let beaconRegion2 = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "...")!, major: 23456, minor: 23456, identifier: "Room2")

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                startScanning()
            }
        }
    }

    func startScanning() {

        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion1)
        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion2)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
       guard region is CLBeaconRegion else {return}
print("Enter: \(region.identifer)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
       guard region is CLBeaconRegion else {return}
print("Exit: \(region.identifer)")
}
```

Comment: Your region states should be independent. Getting a region exit from room1 after a region entry for room2 shouldn't impact the delivery a of room2 exit event. Are you sure it isn't something in your logic that is causing the issue? Is your code as simple as is shown here in the delegate methods? You can also use a single `didDetermineState` delegate callback to handle both entry and exit events

Comment: Yeah- that solved it.  And simplified my code to boot.  I didn't exactly understand that `didDetermineState` was effectively 'didEnterRegion' and/or 'didExitRegion'.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, the delay before a region exit is unavoidable.  The way iOS detects a region exit is that ~20 seconds has passed since the last time a beacon packet was detected.

The job of your computer program is to adapt these beacon events to meaningful real-world events.  **There are countless ways to do this**, and which solutions are appropriate totally depend on the real world events ("use cases") you are trying to solve with your program.

Based on your description, it sounds like you want to know when the user moves the phone from one room to the next.  There are many ways to do this, and which one is best depends on the "requirements" of our system -- how far apart are the rooms?  How quickly do users move from one room to the next?  Where are the beacons placed within the rooms?  Can you ever see two beacons from two rooms at the same time?  **The proper algorithm needed to solve your use case depends on the specific requirements.**

Two ideas:

1. If the rooms are far apart and beacon visibility will not overlap:  Ignore region exits.  Determine which room you are in based on which region entry happened last.  If you ever get a region exit for the same room your program thinks it is already in, then your program should determine it is not in any room at all.
2. If the rooms are close enough that beacon visibility overlaps: Don't use beacon monitoring at all.  Instead use beacon ranging, which gives you an update every second with a list of all visible beacon along with an estimated distance in meters (beacon.accuracy).  The room you are in is determined by which beacon is closest.  When using this approach, you probably also want to add some "debounce" to the closest beacon determination to keep from bouncing back and forth with the noise on the distance estimate.  A simple "debounce" algorithm would be to require that a second beacon be at least 10% closer than the currently tracked room beacon before it will be considered the closest.  You can adjust this percentage to get the best tradeoff between bouncing and time lag to determine the next room.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The rooms are close, which is how a user could end up in Room 2 before the delayed exit is triggered for Room 1.  For this app, we need both enter and exits because we want to calculate time-spent-in-room.  I don't much care that the exit delay will alter the time-spent-in-room by ~30 sec.  Rather, it's that if the first exits comes after the second enter, then didExitRegion does not catch the exit from Room 2 because it thinks it already left...  I updated original question to make clear we need both enter and exits.

Comment: "The way iOS detects a region exit is that ~20 seconds has passed since the last time a beacon packet was detected."  If this is true, I'm not sure that I understand the behavior of `didExitRegion` that I am seeing.  There must be a state that is set when didExitRegion fires such that it needs an interceding didEnterRegion (or a refresh of the didDetermineState) before it will once again register an exit.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified and solved based on replies from @Paulw11 and @davidgyoung.  Thanks.  If I use a single `didDetermineState` as opposed to separate `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` methods, it correctly tracks all enter and exit events for each region regardless of the order of enter and exit events.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
        guard region is CLBeaconRegion else {return}
        print("Event detected: \(state.rawValue) for \(region.identifier)")
```

Of note to other swift novices like me:  `state.rawValue` here returns 0 for unknown, 1 for inside region, and 2 for outside region. `region.identifier` returns the identifier string (in my case, either Room1 or Room2 since I am monitoring for two beacon regions.